# How to load a new component on button click in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I created a main component in `ReactJs` called `MainPage` (using Material-UI).

```
import React from 'react';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import withStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles';

const styles = theme => ({
    card: {
        minWidth: 350,
    },
    button: {
        fontSize: '12px',
        margin: theme.spacing.unit,
        minWidth: 350
    },
    extendedIcon: {
        marginRight: theme.spacing.unit,
    }
});

class MainPage extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        const {
            classes
        } = this.props;

        return ( <
            React.Fragment >
            <
            CssBaseline / >
            <
            Grid container spacing = {
                0
            }
            direction = "column"
            alignItems = "center"
            justify = "center"
            style = {
                {
                    minHeight: '100vh'
                }
            } >
            <
            form onSubmit = {
                this.handleSubmit
            } >
            <
            Card className = {
                classes.card
            } >
            <
            CardContent >
            <
            Grid item xs = {
                3
            } >
            <
            Button variant = "contained"
            size = "medium"
            color = "primary"
            className = {
                classes.button
            }
            type = "submit"
            value = "single" >
            ButtonA <
            /Button> <
            /Grid> <
            Grid item xs = {
                3
            } >
            <
            Button variant = "contained"
            size = "medium"
            color = "primary"
            className = {
                classes.button
            }
            type = "submit"
            value = "batch" >
            ButtonB <
            /Button> <
            /Grid> <
            /CardContent> <
            /Card> <
            /form> <
            /Grid> <
            /React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(MainPage);
```

I want to load a new component (either `CompA` or `CompB`, depending on which button was clicked - ButtonA or ButtonB) on button click. A new component should completely replace a current component - I mean that it should be loaded in a whole screen (not anywhere next to buttons).

How can I do it?

**UPDATE:**

I want to replace MainPage component, not just render on top of it.

This is how I load `MainPage`:

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import MainPage from './components/MainPage';

const View = () => (
  <div>
    <MainPage/>
  </div>
);

render(<View />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: You mean that when the user clicks MainPage gets replaced? Or just rendered above it?

Comment: @0xc14m1z: yes, exactly - I want to replace MainPage!

Comment: What component is rendering `MainPage`? Something like `App`?

Comment: @0xc14m1z: Please see my update. I posted a code to show how I load `MainPage`.

Comment: could [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) help you with that problem?

Comment: @jcal: Can you show me please how to apply it to my case?

Comment: you can find a simple live example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vvoqvk78?from-embed)

Comment: @jcal: What is the proper way to install `react-router`
?

Comment: it's pretty good explained in this tutorial: [https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf](https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf) (it's also the source of the snippet)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a different component to handle the state and add an if statement in that component to handle the view that you want to render.

You can see the example here [codesandbox.io/embed/6wx2rzjrr3](https://codesandbox.io/embed/6wx2rzjrr3)

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Main from "./Main";
import View1 from "./View1";
import View2 from "./View2";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    renderView: 0
  };

  clickBtn = e => {
    this.setState({
      renderView: +e.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    switch (this.state.renderView) {
      case 1:
        return <View1 />;
      case 2:
        return <View2 />;
      default:
        return <Main clickBtn={this.clickBtn} />;
    }
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Main.js

```
import React from "react";

export default props => (
  <>
    Main view{" "}
    <button value={1} onClick={props.clickBtn}>
      View 1
    </button>{" "}
    <button value={2} onClick={props.clickBtn}>
      View 2
    </button>{" "}
  </>
);
```

View1.js

```
import React from "react";

export default props => "View 1";
```

View2.js

```
import React from "react";

export default props => "View 2";
```

Comment: Hmm, an example will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please explain what is `Main class{" "}`? In my case, `MainPage` starts with `const styles = theme => ({`. How can I put the code of `MainPage` into `Main class{" "}`?

Comment: Sure. i will try to change my example to look like your MainPage. my Main view is an example for the general idea of a component with buttons for loading other components. The `const styles = theme => ({` is material ui [jss](https://cssinjs.org/?v=v10.0.0-alpha.7) styling

Comment: Ok. I tried to re-use your solution but got stuck. My level of knowledge of React is insufficient in order to adapt your code to my case. I appreciate if your example could reuse my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186674/discussion-between-meir-keller-and-scalaboy).

Answer (score 6):

In your index.js you can use

```
const View = () => (
  <div>
    <MainPage condition='something' />
  </div>
);
```

Then in you main page:

```
class MainPage extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
      super();
   }

  myCondition1() {
    return (
        <Component1 />
    );
 }


  myCondition2() {
    return (
        <Component2 />
    );
 }

  render() {
     const { condition} = this.props;
     return (
         {condition === 'something' ? this.myCondition1() : this.myCondition2()}
     )
  }
}
```

UPDATE

Here's an example with a simple button:

```js
class Condition1 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>Condition 1</div>
    );
  }
}

class Condition2 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>Condition 2</div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          condition: true
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    
    handleClick(condition) {
      this.setState( {condition} )
    }

  render() {
     const { condition } = this.state;
     return (
         <div>
             <button onClick={() => this.handleClick(true)}>Condition1</button>
             <button onClick={() => this.handleClick(false)}>Condition2</button>
             {condition === true ? <Condition1 /> : <Condition2 />}
         </div>
     )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script><div id="root" />
```

Comment: Is the value of "something" hardcoded? I want to replace `MainPage` on a button click.

Comment: There is no need to hardcode that. It was meant to be a simple solution. Instead of that you can change a variable in the state on a button click and validate that condition to return a component. I just want to show how you can approach that.

Comment: If there are two buttons as in my case, how do I pass a condition to `onClick={this.handleClick}` depending on a button?

Comment: Easier way is to update a state property on each button click indicating what was clicked and read it inside the handleClick method.

Comment: @ScalaBoy I added another button to the code snippet. Hope that helps

Comment: One more question. In my code I have `const { classes } = this.props;` instead of `const { condition } = this.state;`. What happens with `classes`? How can I embed `classes` into your example?

Comment: @ScalaBoy Your code does not interfere with mine. You can have both lines. Or if your classes are specific to Condition1 or Condition 2, you can have const { classes } = this.props in your specific component.

Comment: I tried your code. When I click on any of two buttons, nothing happens (console.log shows that `condition` switches correctly). The only difference is that I do not use `ReactDOM` in `index.js`. My code of `index.js` is the same as in the question. Also I use `export default withStyles(styles)(MainPage)` at the end of `MainPage`.

Comment: If you have time, maybe you could put your code into codesandbox with my `index.js`?

Comment: This part does not work for me `<div> {condition === true ? <Condition1 /> : <Condition2 />} </div>`. It does not load a relevant class into div. Also where do you reload the content of `MainPage`? It looks like you just render Condition1 or Condition2 next to a current page. But I need to replace current page.

Comment: If you need to replace the page then you need to use a solution similar to the one I wrote before the update. But instead of using the hardcoded prop use button's logic to set the props for the main page.